# A lttle confused about invariance

Tags: self-study, estimation

I'd like to know to what extent this principle can be applied. Say I have $X_1,X_2... X_n$ as iid $Normal(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2$ known. I want to find the UMVUE for the following:

1.) $\mu$

2.) $\frac{3\mu+5}{7}$

3.) $1/\mu$

4.) $e^{a\mu}$ for some known constant $a$

I know that the $\bar{x}$ is UMVUE for $\mu$ and applying linearity of expectations, I think it's reasonable to say that I can just substitute $\bar{x}$ for $\mu$ in 2.) to and call that UMVUE for 2.). I know this does not work for 3.) and 4.). What I'd like to ask is what does work for these cases? That is, suppose I know the UMVUE for a parameter $\mu$, how do I use this information to find UMVUEs for functions of $\mu$.

Comment: In case 4, mgf can be used to find the umvue.

Comment: Oh yeah... so, $\bar{x} \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ and $E(e^{\bar{x}t})=e^{\mu t+t^2\sigma^2/2n^2}$ and since $\bar{x}$ is complete and sufficient for $\mu$, $e^{\bar{x}t-t^2\sigma^2/2n^2}$ is UMVUE for $e^{\mu t}$. Is this correct? So there is no "general" procedure.